# What exactly does " from module import * " mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I thought it meant everything in the module. But in tkinter I would have to specifically import things like messagebox, colorchooser and filedialog despite having a "from tkinter import *" command. So exactly what does "import *" mean?

Comment: Answers will let you know what it means, but it is advisable NOT to use it, since it makes the code much less readable. If you want to have it more simple, use `import mycomplexmodule as mm` instead ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A module can define an `__all__` variable: a list containing the names that will be imported when you do `from module import *`. Anything not in this list will not actually be imported.
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Are the names starting with an underscore included in the __all__ variable or are they not imported by default (since they are hidden)?

Comment: in this case this isnt the correct answer... from tkinter import * imports everything from _ _ init _ _ .py file... but functions colorchooser are defined in 2nd file...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If a module's authors decide to include the `__all__` variable, then it's completely up to them to decide what is in there. Though Pythonistas would frown at them if they explicitly include underscored names. If they don't include an `__all__` variable, then only non-underscore-starting names are imported. (Pretend that the default for `__all__` is "every name that doesn't start with an underscore".)

Answer (score -1):

It just means that you import all(methods, variables,...) in a way so you don't need to prefix them when using them.

Comment: I think the actual question is why doesn't it literally import _all_ things that are in the module. For example, `ttk` is in `tkinter` but it doesn't get imported with ` import *`.

Comment: Well: the original question did not ask for that.

Answer (score -3):

```
from module import *
```

This imports all names except those beginning with an underscore (_).

read more:
[Python modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't actually answer the OP's question. Specifically, why doesn't it import messagebox, colorchooser and filedialog? Those don't start with an underscore.